# How to autocomplete a shell command starting with (an alias involving) sudo

Tags: bash, shell, sudo, docker, autocomplete

Assume one has the following alias in your `.bashrc`:

```bash
alias docker='sudo docker'
```

then try to autocomplete `docker run -v /tmp/test:/foo …` in a bash terminal, starting from `docker run -v /tmp`| → due to the presence of `sudo` in the alias, one gets the following distracting behavior:

```
$ docker run -v /tmpTAB
$ docker run -v /tmp[sudo] password for user:
```

and at that point, it is almost impossible to further edit the command line, apart from doing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> and restarting.

Are there solutions to overcome that behavior? namely, keep the `sudo` implied in the alias, but avoid the password prompt when we are just expecting some regular autocompletion.

A solution that is independent of the `alias` feature would be nice (given the issue presented here also arises when typing any `$ sudo command …` directly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relying on @ApolloXI's advice regarding `sudo -n` and doing more experimentations, I was able to overcome the drawback I was mentioning in my [previous comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/622105/how-to-autocomplete-a-shell-command-starting-with-an-alias-involving-sudo#comment1163687_622115).

To sum up, when autocompleting `docker …` commands, the following code is loaded:

- From /etc/bash.bashrc: `. /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`;
- From /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:

  - `__load_completion docker`,
  - then `. /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/docker`;
- From /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/docker:

  - `docker version -f '{{.Client.Experimental}} {{.Server.Experimental}} {{.Server.Os}}`, etc.
  - which re-runs the `docker` command (or the alias, if it exists).

So a working solution would just amount to replace my alias with a bash function, **detecting whether it is called from the bash-completion feature**. This can be done by reading the `BASH_SOURCE` array.

As a result, we could adopt the following solution:

```bash
docker() {
    if [[ "${BASH_SOURCE[*]}" =~ "bash-completion" ]]; then
        sudo -n docker "$@"
    else
        sudo docker "$@"
    fi
}
```

or if we want to be able to easily disable the wrapper, write instead:

```bash
__docker() {
    if [[ "${BASH_SOURCE[*]}" =~ "bash-completion" ]]; then
        docker "$@"
    else
        sudo docker "$@"
    fi
}

alias docker=__docker
```

Then, the `sudo -n` prefix is not necessary anymore, and it is possible to run for example:

```bash
$ \docker run --help
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to avoid a password prompt on `sudo`, try the `-n` option.

The man page for `sudo` reads:

> -n, --non-interactive
>
> > Avoid prompting the user for input of any kind.  If a password is required for the command to run, sudo will display an error message and exit.

Comment: Thanks but that does not work: try `sudo -n docker run -v /tmp`[TAB]

Comment: On second thought, by setting `alias docker='sudo -n docker'` first and trying again, the issue does not occur anymore! thank you :)

Comment: There is a *drawback* though: after setting `sudo -n` in the alias (which is OK at autocompletion time), `sudo` does not ask for the password any longer (at "run" time). Would you think about some way to fix this, "conditionally"?